# How to use system property variable in log4j2.xml in spring boot using lombok log?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, spring-logback

I am having a CommandLineRunner Spring Boot applicatio nwith Sytem property log_prefix.

I am currently using a log24j.xml for setting the log configurations. It is taking the filename etc from the `<properites>` tag in the log24j.xml. Is there a way to change the log fileName to log_prefix_LogFileName ?

My Application.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Application.class.getName());
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("log_prefix",args[0]);// Tried hardcoding a string value
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        springApplication.run(args);
    }
```

I tried setting runID in `Application.class` and using `${log_prefix}` in log42j.xml but not working.

Pom.xml log4j2 dependency.

```
 <log4j2.version>2.15.0</log4j2.version>
```

I am using `@Slf4j` lombok annotaion over the class

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
@Slf4j
```

Comment: Duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132433/one-logfile-per-run-with-log4j

Comment: @HalilİbrahimOymacı updated question for more clarity. I have changed the runID variable to log_prefix for more clarity on the error.

Comment: `Logger.getLogger` is executed before your application starts and it configures Log4j2.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz True, I tried reconfiguring log as in  https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext/reconfigure but didn't work.

Comment: In the config file you must use `${sys:log_prefix}` to access system properties.

Comment: Removing business use case in the question to make it generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Piotr P Karwaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11748454/piotr-p-karwasz?force_isolation=true) pointed out my log config file had `${log_prefix}` , to get system properties in spring boot log configuration log4j2.xml file we need to prefix `sys:` the property name in curly braces. `${sys:log_prefix}` fixed the issue.

note this is specific to Spring boot, for normal java application you can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6558539/20173434)