# Setting a log file name to include current date

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I would like to set the log file name for a log4j to have the current date. I needn't to do rollovers and todays log file should be named with a date. 
As a result I would get a separate log file for each day.

The log file name format would be:

> systemName_DDMMYYYY_moduleName.log

Comment: duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629772/filename-with-date-in-log4j

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to do I know are :-
Use DailyRollingFileAppender ...

```
<appender name="roll" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="application.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" 
          value="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n  %-5p %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

second,

including [apache-log4j-extras](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/)

```
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/logs/application_%d{ddMMyyyy}_moduleName.log
```